# Texas holdem question

Tags: texas-hold-em

If the community cards are Q,,Q,10,10,2 and one players hold cards are a 2 how do you decide the winner if no other player can match any of the community cards?

Comment: just a hint 3 pair is a six card hand, only five cards count, so if the board has two pair, the best hand Q,,Q,10,10 X, X= the largest kicker a player may have, whom ever has the best kicker wins, if two player have the same best kicker the pot splits.

Answer (score 0):

If no one else has a Q, 10, or pair higher than 10, then the player with the single highest fifth card wins. Poker hands have exactly five cards, no more, no less. So if player 1 has, for example, 9-2, the best five-card hand he can play is Q-Q-10-10-9, while player 2's K-5 wins with Q-Q-10-10-K. Under no circumstances do a sixth or seventh card come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient information. The precise answer is winning kicker wins the hand, and if all kickers are void due to being under the board, then it becomes a chop.

Board: Q♥Q♣T♥T♣2♥

Hand: 2♣3⋄, best 5 cards makes Q♥Q♣T♥T♣3⋄, Two pair with kicker on 3

Hand: 4⋄6⋄, best 5 cards makes Q♥Q♣T♥T♣6⋄, Two pair with kicker on 6. This player wins!

As "three pair" is not possible with 5 cards, the best two pairs are kept, then the highest card as kicker.

Another example: Q♥Q♣2♥2♣T♥, this time anyone without a Q, 2 or 10 would either have flush (two hearts) or nothing but two pair, but T♣3♣ would beat A⋄K⋄ (Queen Ten two pair > Queen Deuces two pair)

Another example demonstrating the chop:

Board: Q♥Q♣T♥T♣9♥

Hand: 2♣9⋄, best 5 cards makes Q♥Q♣T♥T♣9⋄, Two pair with kicker on 9

Hand: 4⋄6⋄, best 5 cards makes Q♥Q♣T♥T♣9♥, Two pair with kicker on 9

Both players win and they chop the pot!